# How to sort simple products inside configurable

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, sorting

I have configurable product where i showed the simple products in table formate.Now i want to arrange them in order (`Size` and `Color`) like `2-8` and Alphabitcally like `A` or `B` will comeup first and so one .I try from admin but nothing found there to set the order.How can i set it from front side.I can code but dont know from i change it.I am adding my product detail page [image]

Comment: You just want to rearrange the option based on the condition right ? You can go to catalog\product\view\type\options change the options rendering based on the condition.

Comment: Yes i want to arrange them in asc order by size and color.Do i goto phtml file ? can you tell me little in detail

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar kind of requirement to display the options in my custom order so what i done is i have copiedcatalog\product\view\type\options\configure.phtml to my custom theme.

> $_attributes=Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());

**Add Following code after above line**

```
$_temp=array();

foreach($_attributes as $_attribute) 

{

     //$_attribute->getLabel() You can use label for custom sorting

     if(some condition for sorting)
    {
        $_temp[]=$_attribute;// storing in temp array
    }           
}

$_attribute=$_temp;
```

It is just an example . Just apply your sorting logic in above

Comment: Thanks for your message.Can you specify little more as i pirnt the array and got lots of details.So cannot figure how to set proper logic

Comment: Please print only getLabel so you can figure out sorting logic